# How to create reports page in Directus

Tags: javascript, directus

I want to create report page in Directus, I am programming in JS and PHP but I can not figure out how to embed some code into Directus in order to create reports page from which I could do a query to multiple tables in database and then show results.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a page (an extension) within the Directus App using VueJS.
Basic understanding of JavaScript and VueJS would be required, but once you create the page, you can then query as many collections as you wish to create reports.

For more information see: 
https://docs.directus.io/extensions/pages.html